# Setting config file values for different environments

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

My Selenium automation solution file has several projects to test different parts of the application.
Each of these project has a app.config file like the one below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>

    <appSettings configSource ="app.env2.config">

  </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

So in each of the projects if i change **configSource ="app.env2.config"** to **configSource ="app.env1.config"**, Im able to the **env1** specific values like the url of env1.

But i have to change the configsource values in each of the 12 projects each time I have to test it in a different environment . Is there a way by which if I set the environment value in one place allows me to access the appropriate config file in each of these 12 projects (some way by setting the env(env1/env2) value in a place and then attaching this value to "app.< env >. cofig")

Comment: have you seen config transforms?

Comment: nope.. ill try to google them